# query did not return a unique result: 2 . Issue with Nhibernate Query

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, nhibernate

I am current having an issue with getting records from database using `nhibernate`.

My 'publicstring' column is having two values, one with lower case and the other with upper case.
I am trying to fetch one of them depending on what is typed.

Below is my query

```
 private string _publicId;
 var _mediaFileShare = this.Session.QueryOver<MediaFileShare>()
                                   .Where(q => q.Publicsting == _publicstring)
                                   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answers would be appreciated..

Comment: Couldn't you just make both toupper for the comparison and/or compare case insensitive?

Comment: How to compare case insensitive in nhibernate

Comment: Generally NHibernate just translates the comparison, which is then actually executed in SQL, so Allan certainly meant, you should tell your SQL column to be case insensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive solution is:

```
var _mediaFileShare = this.Session.QueryOver<MediaFileShare>()
    .Where(q => q.PublicString == _publicString)
    .List()
    .SingleOrDefault(r => string.Compare(r.PublicString, _publicString, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);
```

If you're confident that the query will always return two rows then performance should be very acceptable. Alternatively you could use a dynamic order by, something like:

```
    var query = this.Session.QueryOver<MediaFileShare>()
        .Where(q => q.PublicString == _publicString);

    query = _publicString == _publicString.ToLower() 
        ? query.OrderBy(q => q.PublicString) 
        : query.OrderByDescending(q => q.PublicString);

    var _mediaFileShare = query.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

The results using an order by will be dependent on your database and its collation setting.

Comment: It needs to be List(). as in your example you made ToList(). And it should be FirsOrDefault rather than SingleOrDefault.

Comment: I think SingleOrDefault should work, did you try it? FirstOrDefault will work as well.

Comment: The naive solution will fail when more then one result is returned from database and fulfills the SingleOrDefault condition. Add `.SetMaxResults(1)` before List() method. It has also performance benefits.